# Selecting hover on plotly choropleth map

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, choropleth

I am currently working on a map project using choropleth from plotly.express and this map combines two traces: one is the choropleth map with area defined by colors and the second one bubbles to put over some selected countries (not all).

I have two dataframes, one with iso alpha-3 code and the regional area they are apart of (which will define the color on the map) and the second one with a number of client for some countries (with iso alpha-3 code once again)

I managed to merge the two maps,  but I only want the "hover" from the second one for the selected countries (so when my cursor goes to the related dot of the country) and using hovermode=False disables all the hovers on the map... Is there a way to select the hover we want and disabling the other without removing everything?

```
fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="alpha-3",
                color="sub-region",
                color_discrete_map= {"Middle East and Africa":"#2a7bb0",
                                        "Europe":"#fc5e61",
                                        "Asia":"#00a19c",
                                        "Northern America":"#00134d",
                                        "Russia and Central Asia": "#febec0",
                                        "Latin America and the Caribbean":"#99a1b8"})


fig.update_layout(width=1500, height=1000, margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}, hovermode=False)
fig.update_geos(projection_type="mercator", visible=False)
fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=0)

fig2 = px.scatter_geo(dfa, locations="alpha-3", size="actors")
fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0])




aPlot = plotly.offline.plot(fig,
                        config={"displayModeBar": False},
                        show_link=False,
                        include_plotlyjs=False,
                        output_type='div')
```

fig is the choropleth map, fig2 is the circle map. hovermode=False is set before the merge but it's not working. I tried to update the fig2 with fig but the circles were not displayed... I am clueless at this point on how to only have the hover from fig2...

EDIT : Here are an snippet of the dataframes:

```
                     name alpha-3  country-code  region              sub-region
0                Zimbabwe     ZWE           716  Africa  Middle East and Africa
1                  Zambia     ZMB           894  Africa  Middle East and Africa
2            South Africa     ZAF           710  Africa  Middle East and Africa
3                   Yemen     YEM           887    Asia  Middle East and Africa
4                Viet Nam     VNM           704    Asia                    Asia
```

```
                        name  ...                                Actors
0               South Africa  ...                                NameOfAnActor
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your dataframes `df` and `dfa`? you can copy and paste the output from `df.head(10).to_dict()` directly into the question, and do the same thing for `dfa`. this will be really helpful because it allows people to reproduce your problem – thanks!

Comment: @DerekO Done even if without the full dataframe it won't be that useful as you need every countries to recreate the map (and so the issue). Hope it helps anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I will share how I handled the issue which is not perfect but it will maybe help.
The "solution" was to remove every data from the first figure by disabling them with hover_data as follow in the choropleth map variables:

```
hover_data={"alpha-3":False,"sub-region":False}
```

This solution isn't perfect as a pointer is still here on each countries but at least nothing is displayed aside from the bubbles...